# scmStats plugin 0.3.1 works from windows cmd prompt but not from Jenkins job

Tags: sonarqube

I am running sonarqube 5.1.1 and sonar-runner-2.4 from  windows 2012 r2 server
Java version--java version "1.8.0_20"
After running sonar-runner.bat from the command prompt the scm stats plugin is giving the correct output on the sonar dashboard. But when sonar-runner.bat is being run as jenkins (1.617) job it gives following error :
 **Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git whatchanged "--until=2015-06-28 00:01:21 +0000" --date=iso -- C:\sonar_review."
17:01:21.375 INFO  - Working directory: C:\sonar_review.
17:01:21.396 WARN  - Fail to retrieve SCM info. Reason: The git-log command failed.
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

I am getting the same error in sonarqube 4.5.4 .

Answer (score 0):

'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

This is because Jenkins doesn't know where git is installed within your system.

You have to tell Jenkins the installation path of git.

For specifying the git path to Jenkins , go to manage Jenkins > configuring system > search for GIT and specify the git executable command.

Suppose you have git installed in c drive, you have to provide path till git.exe

This will definitely solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have already configured the git path in Jenkins Configure System page. I am able to check out the code from git repository.Sonar analysis is working fine but scm stats analysis is not being done .